# Can't upload file in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I'm trying to make a screen where it allows me to upload a file and make a request to API with the file but I'm encountering a problem. I'm getting
`Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property '0' of undefined` error which points to this line: `const file = e.target.file[0]`, An example of my code is this:

```
import {Form} from 'react-bootstrap'

function RandomScreen() {
    async function uploadFileHandler(e) {
                const file = e.target.file[0]  // This is the error line
                const formData = new FormData()
                formData.append('image', file)
                const config = {
                    headers:{
                        'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data'
                    }
                }
                // Make API request
            }
        return (
             <Form.File onChange={uploadFileHandler}></Form.File>
        )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `const file = e.target.files[0]` instead, ie. `files` not `file`

Comment: You can as well do some `validation` before that, like checking if a file has been attached with a simple if statement e.g. `if(e.target.files.length > 1)`, this will help minimise errors as well as give you more control, likewise you can also check the file type, file size, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use files instead of file. `const file = e.target.files[0]`

It may be helpful for you to read. [Here](https://web.dev/read-files/)